# Placing buttons at the center in horizontal line in QT

Tags: c++, qt

I am new QT and trying to develop the desktop application.

Currently I am facing a issue of alignment. I am using QTCreator 3.1.2 based on qt 5.3.1

I have 3 buttons placed in the windows as
[image]

1. After running application, If I resize the windows then buttons didn't stay in the center. like image 1  and if size is less then it is like image 2
   [image]

[image]

I have tried using the hbox, but it didn't solve the problem and also scroll bar is also not visible in the window.

Would you please tell me how can I make these buttons to stay in the center only?

Thanks a lot

Comment: "I have 4 buttons", you meant 3 right?

Comment: HBoxLayout is definitely a way to go here, what is not working there?

Comment: though I used hbox, here buttons remains at the same place.

Comment: have you set the HBoxLayout as the layout of the central widget ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create `QHBoxLayout` passing `this` as its parent, which will set that layout as the layout of that widget, then add `QPushButton`s to that layout:

```
Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent) {

    // Prepare the horizonal layout, adding buttons
    horizontalLayout = new QHBoxLayout(this);

    pushButton = new QPushButton(this);
    horizontalLayout->addWidget(pushButton);

    pushButton_2 = new QPushButton(this);
    horizontalLayout->addWidget(pushButton_2);

    pushButton_3 = new QPushButton(this);
    horizontalLayout->addWidget(pushButton_3);

    // Set the layout of the central widget
    setLayout(horizontalLayout);    
}
```